# Executing a series of external/3rd party programs in a IF ELIF Statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

My script has a prety long IF ELIF statement in it which works. My problems started when I began trying to get it to execute external programs/3rd party software.

```
.....; then
prog1 -some flags
prog2 -some flags
prog3 -some more flags
prog4 -even more flags
elif [......]
```

As you can gues I have found out that this is not feesable, the only work around I can see is that I put these commands into a seperate shell script and call it as below:

```
.....; then
./myshellscript.sh
elif [......]
```

Is there away of containing this in the script its self without having to call shell scripts to do all my tasks. I would normally bite the bullet and do this but that would mean having hundreds of external shell scripts which would be cluttering up the folder rather than having one deffinitive script containing all the code that is required to carry out the task at hand.

Once again any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "this is not feasible" ? Specifically, what is the desired behavior, and what issues are _you_ running into that are not this behavior?

Comment: When I run the script it just lists all my commands and programs that I wish to execute instead of actually running them. Obviously if I just run this list of programs and commands from a bog standard bash script I have no problems. Howevery when I try to run them while embedded into a IF ELIF statement as above they do not produce the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just concerned about the number of calls to scripts in each branch, and if the scripts, which are called in each branch, are the same, then you could just use bash functions to do the work.

Have a look at [this page](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html), to see how to write functions in bash.

This is basically the same way, as the one in which you would factor out common code into functions in almost any language.

Comment: Functions are looking like a an option at this point. However all the scripts I have are all unique and would only be called once during the running of the script. I was hoping that this could be accomplished by having them embedded within the IF ELIF Statement as I show in my first example.

Comment: Just a thought... is it possible to use the funtion within the IF ELIF statement or do I need to declare this prior to the IF ELIF Statement?

Comment: Then I guess I misunderstood your question. Concerning you final comment, that it just lists the files, this should not be the case usually. I have done a fair amount of if...elif stuff in bash, and I know that this sometimes get's ugly. If your commands are just printed instead of being executed, there probably is some bug in some other part you are not showing. Normally they should be executed.